# How to set compiler options in VS Code and/or .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, compiler-options

I'm trying to set the -checked compiler option for a C# library project written over .NET Core, using VS Code as the IDE.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Most (all?) compiler options have a corresponding build argument. You can pass build arguments to `dotnet build` using the `-p:` (or `/p:`) flag before the argument you intend to add. You then use a `name=value` structure for the argument name and corresponding value.

From the documentation for the [-checked compiler option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/checked-compiler-option#to-set-this-compiler-option-in-the-visual-studio-development-environment), the corresponding build argument is [CheckForOverflowUnderflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/vslangproj80.csharpprojectconfigurationproperties3.checkforoverflowunderflow).

Below is a sample in PowerShell using the `dotnet build` argument `CheckForOverflowUnderflow`, the build equivalent of the `-checked` compiler option.

```
PS C:\Users\me\source\repos\Solution\Solution.Models> dotnet build -p:CheckForOverflowUnderflow=true .\Solution.Models.csproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0+7fb82e5b2 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Solution.Models -> C:\Users\me\source\repos\Solution\Solution.Models\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Solution.Models.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.18
PS C:\Users\me\source\repos\Solution\Solution.Models>
```

Comment: This took a while to find but this is how you can conditionally turn on `-p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true` also

Comment: Where did you find information about `-p:` option?

Comment: You can find the MSBuild CLI reference here (VS 2022 showing): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022. 

Long form of the above parameter is `-property:`. You can add multiple properties as name-value pairs that are semicolon delimited.

Answer (score 1):

When you open your project/solution with VS Code, it will create a directory called `.vscode`, within it there will be a `tasks.json` file

(this directory and file are created the first time that you hit F5 within VS Code)

Taking a look at this file, you'll that it takes a format similar to the following:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/project.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
        }
    ]
}
```

(you may have more task entries)

You can add individual arguments to each task by adding a string to its `args` array. In the above example I am calling the CLI command `dotnet` and passing it the arguments `build` and `${workspaceFolder}/project.csproj`

Comment: That's useful to set the options for the `dotnet` command, but I don't see how you can set compiler flags with those. In fact, typing `dotnet build --help` in the console will print a list of all the options and there's nothing related to the compiler flags.